# Keycloak redirect page shows We are sorry.. page not found

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-connect

I have deployed keycloak on my EKS cluster and able to access dashboard successfully and created a new realm already.

So I thought of testing my keycloak, and went to https://www.keycloak.org/app/ for testing.

I have created a client with the root URL "https://www.keycloak.org/app/" and created one User also.
I have tested successfully my user using account login of my realm.

then I went to https://www.keycloak.org/app/ entered my keycloak URL as https://keycloak.test.nip.io , the realm as Test(same name of my realm), and then client name as a portal(same name client created on keycloak).

When I hit Sign in, it redirects to my keycloak URL but shown We are Sorry... Page not found

Anyone knows why I am receiving this error and how can I avoid that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue fixed. So there is a catch My realm name was Test. So I was entering the same and it was not working and then I tried writing in lowercase as a test. Boom It worked.

TIP: No matter what case your realm name is there, if facing this issue try in Lowercase it solved for me and hope for others also it should work.

Thanks, guys...

Comment: I had the same issue. The error was that the realm was not created in keycloack. After creating the realm, the error has gone.

Comment: really weird, I tried almost everything. I checked typo, convert everything to lovercase and use underscore instead of dash. But it wont work. I just share [my Github poject](https://github.com/kasir-barati/you-say) for those who come later see it. Maybe in the future I resolve it :smile:

Comment: This was my issue. My realm and client actually have the same names but the realm name is capitalized. That fixed it.

Answer (score 17):

I too had this error.  I followed instructions somewhere for configuring the keycloak client application's url, realm, and clientId properties.  In the instructions it said to configure the url to http://localhost:8080/auth.  I think this must have changed somewhere along the way.

Changing the url property to http://localhost:8080 fixed the error :)

Comment: According to migration-to-quarkus document, "/auth removed from the default context path"
https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus

Comment: Jizz... Removed `/auth` helped a lot.

Comment: Oh my God! I added the `/auth` and its working :)